# mvc5 missing in vs 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

## How to install MVC5 in Visual Studio 2015 enterprise

I installed `Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 1` in `Windows 10`, but there is no `MVC5` template,  while creating `ASP.NET MVC` project, only `MVC4` template.

This is the screan short or the problem [this is the problem that i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1ibu.png) , but instead of this I want like this [and this is what i want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D8Te.png)

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the screenshot you have posted you have the choice between WebApi or Web Application and empty, should you wish to do the configuration from scratch. Choosing Web Application will give you a MVC project.

Comment: Web Application :    will it have mvc5 core feature

Comment: Yes, it has views, controllers etc

Comment: and which mvc version will it use mvc4 or mvc5

Comment: MVC 5. If you want MVC 4 you choose the MVC template at the top of the screen.

Comment: No No i want to create a project with mvc5 ....before this i selected the mvc template in top screen but that was the template with c# icon on it as shown in the second screen short but now when i select mvc template in top screen it has mvc4 icon on it which mean i am choosing the mvc4 template :( .